# If $A \times B$ is a cyclic group then $A$ and $B$ are both cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $A$ and $B$ be groups and $A \times B$ their product. Show that if $A \times B$ is cyclic then $A$ and $B$ are both cyclic.

So far I've got:
Assume $A \times B$ is cyclic. Therefore there exists $a_1b_1$ in $A \times B$ such that $A \times B = \langle a_1b_1 \rangle $ equals the subgroup generated by $g$.
I have no idea where to go after getting this, not sure how to prove that $A$ and $B$ are both cyclic from the initial statement.

Comment: The quotient of a cyclic group is cyclic. (or use the theorem that a subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: assuming $\langle(a_1,b_1)\rangle=A\times B$, consider $\langle a_1\rangle\subseteq A$.

Comment: I know that to prove what I'm trying to prove I need to get ⟨a1⟩ = A and ⟨b1⟩ = B but I'm not sure how to get there from what I'm given just about A x B being cyclic.

Comment: @SuprDooprPoopr Take an arbitrary $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. We want to know whether $a\in \langle a_1\rangle$ and $b\in\langle b_1\rangle$. We know that $(a,b)\in \langle (a_1,b_1)\rangle$. Now use the definition of cyclic group and of $\times$ to conclude.

Comment: A group G is called cyclic if ∃a ∈ G such that
G =< a > equals the (sub)group generated by a, and a is called a generator of G. How can I use this to prove that a∈⟨a1⟩ and b∈⟨b1⟩?

Comment: For any $a_2\in A$ we know that $(a_2,1_B)\in A\times B = \langle(a_1,b_1)\rangle$. So ....

Comment: @JaapScherphuis so a2 ∈ <(a1)>?

Comment: Yes (though you may need to fill in a few steps to properly prove that), and since $a_2$ was an arbitrary element of $A$ that means ....?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis every element of A is generated by <(a1)> meaning it is a cyclic group? (and how can I prove that a2 ∈ <(a1)> like you mentioned in your edit?)

Comment: I'd rather say that it shows that $A\subseteq \langle a_1 \rangle$, and since it is obvious that $\langle a_1 \rangle \subseteq A$ we get $A = \langle a_1 \rangle$, i.e. $A$ is cyclic, generated by $a_1$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis and the same logic works for B as well, but how can I prove that a2 ∈ <(a1)> and the same for b2 respectively?

Comment: What is the definition of a cyclic group? What does that tell you about the element $(a_2, 1)$ of the cyclic group $\langle(a_1,b_1)\rangle$ ?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis it means that ⟨(a1,b1)⟩ equals the (sub)group generated by a1,b1, and since (a2,1) is part of A x B it means (a2,1) is generated by it?

Comment: Ok, the element $(a_2,1)$ is generated by $(a_1,b_1)$. What does "is generated" mean more explicitly? Use the definition of the group operation of the cross product group $A\times B$ to show that this means that $a_2$ is generated by $a_1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily verify such that every subgroups of cyclic group is an cyclic group, and $G$ and $G\times\{1\}$ is isomorphic.

Then, $A\times\{1_B\}, \{1_A\}\times B$ are subgroups of $A\times B$.